# if a database object is source controlled is it necessary to also note changes in the tombstone?

Tags: database, version-control, stored-procedures

If I have a procedure definition that has been stored in source control, is it necessary or helpful to keep the 'tombstone' up to date as well?

Here's what I mean by a 'tombstone':

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[getCreditTransactions]      
AS   
/*
2001-02-12 jdoe : created proc
2003-04-15 kdoe : added handling for credit business rules 
*/
etc...
```

Comment: If you're going to vote for close it would be helpful if you said why. Maybe the question can be edited?

Comment: I didn't vote, but it's a claim that this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877519/is-it-ok-to-put-comments-about-bug-fixes-in-the-source-code

Comment: @OMGP: I see. Thanks. Certainly not a duplicate since that q is about code and this one is about database objects. There are plenty of people that see them differently. Not that I'm trying to convince you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not update the tombstone, would assume that people *are* entering pertinent information when checking the update into source control.  This was a big problem at my last job - it was company policy but there was no means of implementing business rules to enforce the behavior.

A benefit of having the tombstone updated would be:

- to see history without needing access to source control
- if source control software was changed - the history wouldn't be lost.

Comment: it seems like a problem along the lines of code review: the only way to get people to put good comments in source is to check up on their butts from time to time. I wonder if most good SCMs have a switch for forcing people to put in comments. Still, I find the tombstone to be of really dubious value. Like anyone could really use that tombstone to put the proc/view/whatnot back to the state it was in before the change.

Comment: @jcollum: The shop used JIRA, and commits were supposed to quote the jira issue number at a minimum.  There was talk of integration/testing to ensure they were valid but nothing came of it in the time I was there.

Comment: @jcollum: Confluence too?  If so, you are doomed! DOOMED! :)

Comment: the only answer wins by default!